# How to print out lines longer than specific lenght

Tags: python

I have an input file like this:

```
@sample1
ATGGTTCCAAGGCCTTGGTTAATTGGGGGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT

@sample2
TTGGAACCTTGGCCAATTAAGGGGGGGGGTTTTTTTCCCCCCCCCCCCC

@sample3
GGTTGGTTGGGAATTTGGTTAACCTTTTTAAATTTTTTTTTTTGGGGGG
AATTTTTTTTTTTTTGG
```

I want to print out the line that have specific minimum length. For example, if the minimum length I want is 66, then the output will be :

```
@sample3
GGTTGGTTGGGAATTTGGTTAACCTTTTTAAATTTTTTTTTTTGGGGGG
AATTTTTTTTTTTTTGG
```

Since only the sequence of sample 3 have the minimum length 66

Below is my code sofar:

```
    fastfile = {}
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line:
                continue
            if line.startswith("@"):
                sequencenumber = line[1:]
                if sequencenumber not in fastfile:
                    fastfile[sequencenumber] = []
                continue
            sequence = line
            fastfile[sequencenumber].append(sequence)

            output = []
            for key, value in fastfile.items():
                if len(value) >= sys.argv[2]:
                    output.append(value)
                    print (output)
```

Argv[1] is the path of the input file and argv[2] is the specific minimum length.

Answer (score 1):

You want the values of the fastfile dictionary to be strings not lists, so instead of appending consecutive sequences to a running list, you need to concatenating them to a running string:

```
fastfile = {}
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        if line[0] == "@":
            sequencenumber = line[1:]
            if sequencenumber not in fastfile:
                fastfile[sequencenumber] = ""
            continue
        fastfile[sequencenumber] += line

output = []
for key, value in fastfile.items():
    if len(value) >= sys.argv[2]:
        output.append(value)
print (output)
```

Or if you need to store the strings in a list like you originally do, then use `"".join(value)` to concatenate all the strings together, like so:

```
output = []
for key, value in fastfile.items():
    if len("".join(value)) >= sys.argv[2]:
        output.append("".join(value))
output
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks much simpler:

```
with open(argv[1]) as fin :
    text = fin.read()

min_length = int(argv[2])

parts = text.split('@')
# choose only the parts that have strings over the min_length
parts = [p for p in parts if any(len(i) > min_length for i in p.split('\n'))]

output = '@'.join( parts )
```

Comment: I think what the OP is looking for is more like `parts = [p for p in parts if len("".join(p.splitlines()[1:])) >= min_length]`

Comment: @Stuart could be. hard to tell. hope (s)he is smart enough to choose the correct code